# Posting in sandbox tells me it has more than 30 answers

Tags: bug, status-declined, answers

If I try to post an answer in the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/344), it tells me the following:

> This question has more than 30 answers already.
>
> Did you read through all the existing answers first to make sure your answer will be contributing something new?
>
> Also, please note that you can click the edit link on any of these answers to improve them.

I'm not sure if this warning is entirely appropriate. Would it be possible to disable it for the sandbox?

Comment: Is it really such a problem? It's just a minor thing that you have to dismiss.

Comment: I don't think the moderators would have that level of control as to disable specific messages.

Comment: @PhiNotPi Moderators probably cannot, but I think developers can, at least if they find it worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Did you read through all the existing answers first to make sure your answer will be contributing something new?

I don't think this is inappropriate at all. You might not need to read *all* of the existing answers, but you should at least run a search to see if something similar has been suggested before. If so, you may notice issues that would naturally come up in your challenge.

Either way, it's at most a reminder to check for duplicates.

> Also, please note that you can click the edit link on any of these answers to improve them.

This only really applies if you *did* find an almost identical post. It's probably not worded perfectly for the sandbox, but I don't see why it would be worth developer time to customize the warning for a single question on a single meta.

Comment: I see, you're right, I guess.